# How many facebook friends I can tag on my Facebook photo?

Tags: facebook

How many friends I can tag on my Facebook photo?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of friends you can tag in a photo on Facebook is 50. Read this help document https://www.facebook.com/help/217258071632275/